# C# Updating TextBox from multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I was putting together a simple WinForm that would spawn a number of threads to loop from 0 to 10000 - the purpose of this - to slow down Windows to make some other programs run slow.

Basically the form has a text box that I want to write the loop index to from each thread.  All was fine for a single thread, but since I have introduced more threads, I would appear to hang the application when I click on the Stop button - I am not too sure where to go from here.

My sample is probably not written well.  I want to get a better understanding of multithreadding, deadlocks, etc.  I have dabbled a little with BackgroundWorker in the past, but have been doing Java for the majority of the last 2+ years.

**Form1.cs**

```
public delegate void SetTextDelegate(string text);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Thread[] _slow;
    private object lockTextBox = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Event Handlers

    private void ui_btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ui_btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_slow != null)
        {
            StopAllThreads();
        }

        _slow = new Thread[ (int) numNoOfTheads.Value ];
        for( int i = 0; i < numNoOfTheads.Value; i++)
        {
            _slow[i] = new Thread(ThreadRunLoop);
            _slow[i].Start();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_slow != null)
        {
            StopAllThreads();
        }
    }

    private void ui_btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_slow != null)
        {
            StopAllThreads();
        }
    }

    private void ui_btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Clear();
    }

    #endregion

    protected void ThreadRunLoop()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                UpdateText("Loop " + i + " for " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadInterruptedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread has been interrupted.");
        }
    }

    private void UpdateText(string text)
    {
        //lock (lockTextBox)
        //{
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new SetTextDelegate(UpdateText), text);
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.SuspendLayout();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + text + System.Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                textBox1.ResumeLayout();

            }
        //}
    }

    private void StopAllThreads()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _slow.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_slow[i] != null)
            {
                _slow[i].Interrupt();
                _slow[i] = null;
            }
        }
        _slow = null;
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ui_btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.ui_btnStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.ui_btnStop = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.ui_btnClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.numNoOfTheads = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numNoOfTheads)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // ui_btnClose
        // 
        this.ui_btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(433, 268);
        this.ui_btnClose.Name = "ui_btnClose";
        this.ui_btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.ui_btnClose.TabIndex = 0;
        this.ui_btnClose.Text = "Close";
        this.ui_btnClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.ui_btnClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ui_btnClose_Click);
        // 
        // ui_btnStart
        // 
        this.ui_btnStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.ui_btnStart.Name = "ui_btnStart";
        this.ui_btnStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.ui_btnStart.TabIndex = 1;
        this.ui_btnStart.Text = "Start";
        this.ui_btnStart.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.ui_btnStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ui_btnStart_Click);
        // 
        // ui_btnStop
        // 
        this.ui_btnStop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 41);
        this.ui_btnStop.Name = "ui_btnStop";
        this.ui_btnStop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.ui_btnStop.TabIndex = 2;
        this.ui_btnStop.Text = "Stop";
        this.ui_btnStop.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.ui_btnStop.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ui_btnStop_Click);
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 12);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both;
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(415, 241);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // ui_btnClear
        // 
        this.ui_btnClear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(352, 268);
        this.ui_btnClear.Name = "ui_btnClear";
        this.ui_btnClear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.ui_btnClear.TabIndex = 4;
        this.ui_btnClear.Text = "Clear";
        this.ui_btnClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.ui_btnClear.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ui_btnClear_Click);
        // 
        // numNoOfTheads
        // 
        this.numNoOfTheads.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 98);
        this.numNoOfTheads.Name = "numNoOfTheads";
        this.numNoOfTheads.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 20);
        this.numNoOfTheads.TabIndex = 5;
        this.numNoOfTheads.Value = new decimal(new int[] {
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0});
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 82);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(83, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 6;
        this.label1.Text = "No. Of Threads:";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(520, 303);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.numNoOfTheads);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ui_btnClear);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ui_btnStop);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ui_btnStart);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ui_btnClose);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Slow My Machine";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numNoOfTheads)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button ui_btnClose;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button ui_btnStart;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button ui_btnStop;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button ui_btnClear;
    private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown numNoOfTheads;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}
```

**Update**
If I move the lock to the else in the UpdateText method and add a Thread.Sleep(20); in the loop, then my GUI is more responsive and I can click on the Stop button and move the form around.

Any feedback, fixes will be appreciated.

Comment: might be a bad answer or not an answer at all, why dont you make the update function synchronized ?

Comment: Still the same effect with lots of threads.

Comment: ok so you are making blocking calls, that is why the UI is freezing, make an async call to the blocking function.

Answer (score 4):

The `lock` inside `UpdateText` will cause a deadlock. The worker thread acquires the lock and then calls `Invoke`. The UI thread then calls tries to acquire the *same* lock, but has to wait until it is released. The thing is that the lock will never get released because `Invoke` blocks until the UI thread has finished executing the delegate. That never happens because the UI thread is still waiting to acquire the lock. Deadlock!

Comment: Thanks for that bit of info Brian +1

Answer (score 2):

Change the for loop to

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
       var text = "Loop " + i + " for " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
       if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
          textBox1.Invoke(new SetTextDelegate(UpdateText), text);
       else
          UpdateText(text);
    }
```

And change the UpdateText to

```
    private void UpdateText(string text)
    {
       textBox1.SuspendLayout();
       textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + text + System.Environment.NewLine;
       textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
       textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
       textBox1.ResumeLayout();
     }
```

**EDIT**: My mistake. This will just improve the organization and not in any aspect. If you want to update the UI so frequently you should use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) what rdkleine said.

Comment: Not too sure how that helps sorry.  It is just moving the UpdateText call into the loop?

Comment: @Andez Sorry, it is my mistake. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the lock in UpdateText to inside the else.

Comment: Tried that but the UI becomes unresponsive and you cannot move the form or click on the Stop button.

Comment: I can add a Thread.Sleep(20) in the loop which makes the form more responsive.  This works ok for 2 threads, but if I have 8 I am back to the main problem with the form being unresponsive.

Comment: in this case, `Application.DoEvents();` might be a better bet than `Thread.Sleep();`

Comment: Yes, my mistake - UpdateText should be single threaded anyway, so you should not need to use lock.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BackgroundWorker which updates the UI thread.

Here a good example how to use the BackgroundWorker:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

It doesn't explain how to retrieve the data (your int value) and put it in a textbox but it is a good start.